# Volume of a solid of revolution around the line $x=2$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I would like a hint to help me solve this question.

> Find the volume of region B by rotating the region around x = 2.

[image]

This is what I have worked out:

Outer radius $= 2$
Inner radius $= 2 - \sqrt{y -2}$

$$V = \pi \int_{ 0 }^{ 6 }{ 2^{ 2 }-{ (2-\sqrt { y-2 } )) }^{ 2 } }  $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You are using slicing, I would use cylindrical shells. But let's go on with your basic strategy.

We are rotating the region $B$ about $x=2$.

(i) From $y=0$ to $y=2$, we get a cylinder. Integration is unnecessary, but we can use $\int_0^2 \pi(2^2)\,dy$.

(ii) From $y=2$ to $y=6$, our radius is $2-x$, that is, $2-\sqrt{y-2}$.

Calculate the volumes (1) and (ii), and add.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
Why is it not possible to do it as one integral?

Comment: Never mind, I see that x = sqrt(y-x)
Undefined from y= 0 to y = 2

Comment: There is what you pointed out. But I prefer to look at the situation *geometrically*. From $0$ to $2$ the region we are rotating has different shape than from $2$ to $6$.

Comment: I'm still curious as whether there is a way to do it as one integral. My textbook didn't mention using the shell method (it's the next chapter) so I just assumed you could like the previous problems.

Comment: Shell method gives $\int_0^2 2\pi(2-x)(x^2+2)\,dx$. But what er did above is one integral, plus finding volume of a cylinder. You could instead rotate $A$, $y=2$ to $6$, subtract from cylinder of base radius $2$ height $6$. No simpler.